# Attempting to grab text from a JTextfield, pass it to a method, make method false if the text is found - Cannot find symbol getText error

Tags: java, boolean

So I'm attempting to limit the number of times a user enters a dot in the mini calculator GUI I created. For this I created a method (containsDot() ) that, if false, should stop the if statement from allowing the user to insert a dot.

Here is the tidbit for the event listener, and below is the containsDot method which is currently throwing the "error: cannot find symbol" on variable charAt, variable getText of type String...

How to fix this error and the method work?

```
    if((event.getSource()==dot)&&(!containsDot(answerField))) {
        answerField.append(".");
        }

        if(event.getSource()==buttonCE) {
        answerField.setText("");
        }

    }       
}



    public boolean containsDot(JTextArea answerField){
        int x;
        String dots = ".";
        char d = dots.charAt(0);

        String[] getText = new String[1];
        getText[0] = answerField.getText();

        for(x = 0; x < getText.length; x++){
            if(getText.charAt[x]==d){
                return false; 
            }

        } 
    }
```

Comment: It should be `getText[0].length` and `getText[0].charAt(x)`. Better yet, you should use a `String` instead of a `String[]` or even better, use `answerField.getText().contains(".")`.

Comment: also you can just do `char d = '.'`

Comment: `answerField.getText().toCharArray`

Comment: thanks @Titus turns out the answerField.getText().contains(".") was really al that was necessary instead of using a method! solved it

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a String instead of array of Strings:

```
String getText = answerField.getText();
```

You should iterate over chars inside a String, not by String in 1-element array:

```
for(x = 0; x < getText.length(); x++){
    if (getText.charAt(x) == d) {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

charAt() is a function, so you can't access characters in a String like this:

```
getText.charAt[x]
```

you have to change it to:

```
getText.charAt(x)
```

As @pvg mentioned, you don't have to create a String and then retrieve a dot char, you can to do it right away:

```
    char d = '.';
```

I guess best implementation of this method (credits to @Titus) could be to reuse existing method in String class:

```
public boolean containsDot(JTextArea answerField){
    return answerField.getText().contains(".");
}
```

Comment: You might also want to address `if(getText[0].charAt(x) == d) {`